# How to Create Custom Post Type through REST API with all the CUSTOM FIELDS? WORDPRESS WP-API

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest, api

I'm trying to create custom post-type "property" from REST Api. And i'm able to create it successfully i just passed title and content. BUT i also want to insert the values to the meta boxes like CITY,  Price, Type, Status  Country. These are the part of HOUZEZ theme. How can i create this post type PROPERTY with all these values?? please suggest.

This is My Code as of now. Please suggest what to add.

```
<?php
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                               //
// This is using a sample local WordPress Install and is not production safe     //
// It uses the  REST and Basic Auth plugins                                      //
//                                                                               //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// setup user name and password
$username = '*****';
$password = '*****';
// the standard end point for posts in an initialised Curl
$process = curl_init('http://205.147.97.184/unified/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/property');
// create an array of data to use, this is basic - see other examples for more complex inserts
$data = array('slug' => 'rest_insert2' , 'title' => 'REST API insert22w' , 'content' => 'The content of our stuff', 'excerpt' => 'smaller', 'status' => 'publish' , 'property_city-all' => 'in-property_city-145' );
$data_string = json_encode($data);
// create the options starting with basic authentication
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// make sure we are POSTing
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
// this is the data to insert to create the post
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
// allow us to use the returned data from the request
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
// we are sending json
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);
// process the request
$return = curl_exec($process);
curl_close($process);
// This buit is to show you on the screen what the data looks like returned and then decoded for PHP use
echo '<h2>Results</h2>';
print_r($return);
echo '<h2>Decoded</h2>';
$result = json_decode($return, true);
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);
```

also here is the PROPERTY post type custom meta fields or meta boxes. for which i want to insert the values of it through API

[Property Post Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUhIJ.png)

Comment: do not post sensitive information publically like username password.

Comment: I have the same issue. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation of how to add metadata support in houzez, the original idea is:

[How to include META fields in Wordpress API Post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460557/how-to-include-meta-fields-in-wordpress-api-post)

You need to set:

- 'show_in_rest' true when register_post_type()
- 'custom-fields' must be in 'support' when register_post_type()
- 'show_in_rest' true when register_meta()

When you do these modifications you must think in:

- Don´t modify directly the theme and/or plugin, because when it
  updates you lost the modifications
- Only need to add what you need, only it

In the folder example/, you can find examples in different themes and plugins, at this moment only exist one example but in the future, I can add more

**houzez**

You must activate the child theme and child plugin

*houzez-child*

path: wp-content/themes

houzez child theme, add 'show_in_rest' in meta fields

*houzez-theme-functionality-child*

path: wp-content/plugins

child plugin, add 'custom-fields' to support

The files are in my [repo](https://github.com/XavierZambrano/add-rest-api-support)